# Scrapy: Record the original URL requested using text file in case of a URL redirect

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am scraping from a list I have in a text file.  The website I am scraping has many cases where the URL from the text file redirects to another URL.  I would like to be able to record both the original URL in the text file and the redirected URL.

My spider code is as follows:

```
import datetime
import urlparse
import socket
import scrapy

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

from ..items import TermsItem


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic"
    allowed_domains = ["web"]

    # Start on a property page
    start_urls = [i.strip() for i in open('todo.urls.txt').readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Create the loader using the response
        l = ItemLoader(item=TermsItem(), response=response)

        # Load fields using XPath expressions
        l.add_xpath('title', '//h1[@class="foo"]/span/text()',
                    MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))
        l.add_xpath('detail', '//*[@class="bar"]//text()',
                    MapCompose(unicode.strip))

        # Housekeeping fields
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        l.add_value('spider', self.name)
        l.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        l.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())

        return l.load_item()
```

My Items.py is as follows:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class TermsItem(Item):
    # Primary fields
    title = Field()
    detail= Field()
    # Housekeeping fields
    url = Field()
    project = Field()
    spider = Field()
    server = Field()
    date = Field()
```

Do I need to make a 'callback' that somehow associates with the i.strip() from

```
start_urls = [i.strip() for i in open('todo.urls.txt').readlines()]
```

and then add a field in items.py to load into the #Housekeeping fields?

I originally tested replacing:

```
l.add_value('url', response.url)
```

with

```
l.add_value('url', response.request.url)
```

but this produced the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `handle_httpstatus_list` property in your spider. Consider the below example

```
class First(Spider):
    name = "redirect"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302, 304, 307]
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        if 300 < response.status < 400:
            redirect_to = response.headers['Location'].decode("utf-8")
            print(response.url + " is being redirected to " + redirect_to)

            # if we need to process this new location we need to yield it ourself
            yield response.follow(redirect_to)
        else:
            print(response.url)
```

The output of the same is

```
2017-09-21 11:00:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET http://www.google.com> (referer: None)
http://www.google.com is being redirected to http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw
2017-09-21 11:00:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw> (referer: None)
http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw is being redirected to https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw&gws_rd=ssl
2017-09-21 11:00:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw&gws_rd=ssl> (referer: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw)
https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XU7DWYDrNquA8QeT0ZW4Cw&gws_rd=ssl
```

Comment: Tarun, thanks for the assistance.  I am extremely ignorant about how to use HttpErrorMiddleware so I think it will  take me time to understand your supplied answer (in case you wonder why it will take me a while to hit the 'accept answer' check mark).  In the meantime, do you know of anywhere I could learn more about HttpErrorMiddleware implementation other that the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) ? I am open to reading any blogs, or sites you know of?

Comment: The middleware basically handles common errors itself. If you want to log a specific error or handle yourself then you use this, either at scraper level or at request level, see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html also for request level options. I am not aware of sites, I just follow the documentation